# App settings not present in system settings in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I've created a flutter app. One of the functionalities I'm creating requires location access and once the user denies the permission there's no way to enable it manually and system doesn't display dialogs on subsequent requests.

The reason it can't be done manually is that there's no application entry in system settings (at least in iOS simulator - that's the only iOS instance I can test on myself). What do I do to make it appear?

Answer (score 25):

iOS uses settings bundle to display applications in system settings. Turns out Flutter is not creating it upon project creation.

In order to create it:

1. Open `ios` folder in xcode
2. Open `Runner` entry in the project view, it should contain a bunch of folders, one of which is `Runner` again
3. Right-click the inner `Runner` entry
4. Select `New file...`
5. Select `Settings Bundle` and confirm the selection (then press `create` with default settings)
6. Open `Root.plist` file and remove all `Preference Items` so that the array is empty

Once you reinstall the app, an entry in settings should appear. Once you request some permission (e.g. location) and deny/approve it, it should be automatically added there.

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you so much

Comment: This worked and I'm able to see my app appear in Settings, but going into Settings > myApp I'm still unable to see permissions that I had denied before.  What might be the cause for this?